# Resizing JFrame when child resizes: how to keep up?

Tags: java, swing, scala, resize

I'm trying to work with a `JFrame` (actually, `Frame` in Scala's Swing wrapper, though I don't see why this should matter) that contains a `BoxLayout` which has several items, one of which changes size in response to a button click (another item in the `BoxLayout`).

When resizing, the button event handler does the following:

1. Call a method on the item (`JPanel`) that changes size; this calls `setPreferredSize` for that component.
2. Call `pack` on the `JFrame`
3. Call `repaint` on the `JFrame`

This works with one very strange caveat: the JFrame is always one step behind.  So if I set my preferred x sizes to 100, 200, 300, 200, 100 the JFrame will have width 100, 100, 200, 300, 200.

What might be going wrong, and how do I get the size changes to propagate out to the JFrame window size when they're supposed to?

(More possibly but hopefully not relevant details: Ubuntu 10.10 with Sun Java 1.6.0_24.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you change the size of a component I would try to revalidate() the parent container so the layout manager can be invoked again which will recalculate all the sizes properly.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. And first try this with a JFrame so if there is still a problem you will know if the standard JDK classes or Scala is causing the problem.

Comment: That did it--revalidate _on the `BoxLayout`_, not any combination of validate/invalidate on the `JFrame`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with camickr that `revalidate()` must be used instead of `pack()`. To fix the "one step behind" try to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.